# AMP: Is there any difference in using query string parameter "?amp=1" or subfolder "/amp"?

Tags: php, wordpress, amp-html

Some time ago I needed to create an AMP version in a website. The website has no the default Wordpress structure. Had many custom posts, many custom taxonomies, custom archives and, to create an AMP endpoint was very hard. But, it worked.

Now, I have to do the same thing, but in 2 other websites. First in an existent wordpress website and other with a custom CMS.

I did not want to change the URL structure because the two sites have a large structure.

The most easy way is to add a query string parameter.

Instead of writing the URL this way: `www.website.com/page-permalink-here/amp`, I would like to writing this way: `www.website.com/page-permalink-here/?amp=1`

In Wordpress case, I just have to identify the query string.
If has `$_GET['amp'] && $_GET['amp'] == 1`, I load the AMP theme version. If `false`, loads the regular theme folder.

Wordpress has the function `wp_is_mobile()`. If `wp_is_mobile() == true` and `$_GET['amp'] && $_GET['amp'] == 1` returns false, I can redirect the current URL, adding the `?amp=1` in the URL.

I can do this in reverse as well. If the URL has `amp=1` but `wp_is_mobile() == false`, I can redirect the URL without the `?amp=1`.

In the other website (custom CMS), I would like to do the same.

But, all references suggested to use the subfolder `/amp/` as AMP endpoint. **Is wrong OR is not a good practice to use the endpoint as query string?**

I appreciate all thoughts! Tks!

Comment: I think most of the time query strings are discouraged because of seo, looks cleaner, and is easier to remember. As you mentioned though the two can be re-directed to one or the another. It basically comes down to what your needs are and as long as they both function the same way then it's personal preference.

Comment: You can even to not mention the word amp in your URL it doesn't give any profit for you and only depends on your controller's requirements and its implementation

Comment: Query strings can be more frustrating to work with, however according to this thread they are better supported: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-amp-to-amp-and-amp-home-page-not-working/

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/ampproject/amp-wp/issues/2204

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question and now I use with parameter.
My thought was about a litte from SEO view.

- With "/amp" is a deeper subfolder
- incoming links that stripped parameter goes to one site (see tip down)
- social links are goes to the site without the parameter, to the cannonical url.
- Inside my CMS I have one document for both and I can check easy Querystring for stuff that need difference for AMP

But both with paramter or /amp both works fine. Look what is easy to handle for you.

**Tip: If you use parameter, don't forget to setup the parameter in the search console (Webmaster tools)**